# PHPWord : X and Y location of a table on the page?

Tags: php, phpword

Is there a way in **PHPWord** to sepecify **X and Y location** i.e a static position of a table on a page.
I would like to have something like on the following image, the table is represent by the black square(will contain a profil picture) on the image.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How about creating a whole width table where the text information is in the left cell and the image (or another table) in the right cell?